# Solving this pattern using abs() [I GOT MY OUTPUT.. CLOSED]

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, turbo-c

P.S. I'm a beginner and I was trying to find the following output :

```
         1 
      1  2  3 
   1  2  3  4  5 
1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
   1  2  3  4  5 
      1  2  3 
         1
```

and here's my try :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main() {    
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);   

    for(int i=1;(i<=2*n);i++){
        int temp=1,t=2*n-1;     
           
        for(int j=0;j<abs(n-i);j++){
            printf("  ");
        } 
        for(int j=t;j>=abs((2*(i-1))-t);j--) {            
            printf(" %d",temp);
            temp++;
        }                 
    printf("\n");        
    }    
}
```

as you can see.. I tried my best to remove the i=n condition UNSUCCESSFULLY. or if anyone can provide a more easier way to print the pattern.. I'd my grateful

Comment: What do you get when you run your version?

Comment: C++ is not C. Please format your code blocks properly.

Comment: Please apply consistent indentation.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the i=n" condition? Where is that condition? What do you expect the result of removing it to be?

Comment: I don't understand.  Why is it important to remove a particular condition from the program?

Comment: Is the desired output for the input `4` or some other value?

Comment: @nicomp I get
   1
  123
 12345
1234567
 1234567
   12345
     123
       1

I want to remove that extra 7 digit line

Comment: `int` is the *only* conforming return type for `main()` in a hosted C implementation.

Comment: @Yunnosch i increments from 0 to 2n.. at i=n
it prints a line that I dont want..

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yup for 4.. maybe I should have used 4 directly instead of declaring a variable but ye.. for that pattern, the input should be 4

Comment: @JohnBollinger cauz it prints a line I dont need in my output

Comment: No, it doesn't?  Your program prints almost the specified output for me (with input "4").  There are no extra lines, but the first  several lines are each indented one level fewer than they should be.

Comment: How about using two outer loops? First for printing increasingly long lines. Second for printing one fewer decreasingly long lines. That should allow you to program more straightforward, drop the `abs()` and get rid of whatever awkward construct you do not like ... even if I still cannot find it in your shown code.

Comment: Thanks for indentation. Now drop three quarters of your white space, if I may propose that.

Comment: If really you just want not printing the nth line, you can try inserting at the beginning of the outer loop `if(i==n) continue;`

Comment: @Damien but that would devoid me of the required white space.. and not print a symmetric pattern. right ??

Comment: You have updated the question title to emphasize use of `abs()`.  Is it actually important to use that function?

Comment: FYI, updating the title with the question status isn't how SO is supposed to work. Rather, you should accept an answer as correct, including one you write yourself if you feel so inclined. SO is meant to serve as a database of information for future users. Simply saying "I found my answer" in the title but neglecting to post it is useless for any future visitors, you might as well delete this post.

Comment: Title modification rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

For a given positive input `n`, you want to print `2 * n - 1` lines.

Now consider the indent of each line: it counts from `n - 1` positions down to 0, then back up to `n - 1`.  If you number the lines starting with 1, then that indent is `abs(n - line)` positions.

The count of numbers to print on each line can be viewed as a function of the indent: the maximum is `2 * n - 1`, and each unit of indent reduces that by 2.  With a bit of rearrangement, that gives a maximum value to print on each line of `2 * (n - indent) - 1`.

That should be sufficient information for you to write a program that prints your pattern, using a single outer loop over all the pattern lines, and employing the `abs()` function meaningfully.  The details are left as the exercise they are meant to be.

Comment: Looking carefully at he figure, the ident is `n_blank = 3 * abs(line - n) + 1;`, with 1-indexed `line`.

Comment: Well, @Damien, it depends a bit on what you consider the indent and what you consider the (possibly space-padded) field.  Anyway, when I say "positions", I am being generic -- not a number of characters, but a number of indentation units, whatever those happen to be.  Obviously, if there is a desire for an additional fixed indent on each line then that can be handled as a separate matter.